# sed command - Replace string in file

Tags: shell-script, sed, xml

I want to modify a value in my `server.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="9001" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <!--
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  -->
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8180" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->

    <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />



    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvmB04905-2">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I want to replace the value `jvmRoute=` with an another value

***Example:***

*old value:*

`<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvmB04905-2">`

*new value:*

`<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="VALUE10">`

When I execute this command:

```
sed -i '/^jvmRoute=/s/=.*/=VALUE10/' server.xml
```

Nothing has changed in my file, why?

Comment: Next problem you will run into is that you change everything until the end of the line, but you neither replace `"` nor `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed` :

```
 sed -E  's/(jvmRoute=)([a-zA-Z0-9"-])+/\1"VALUE10"/g'
```

As you have not specified what can the original `jvmRoute` value be, i wrote the regex for the above example, but you can customize it for your needs.
To replace directly in the file, use :

```
sed -i -E  's/(jvmRoute=)([a-zA-Z0-9"-])+/\1"VALUE10"/g' server.xml
```

But using the xml parser would be the best way probably.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sed` command won't change anything because your file does not contain any line that starts with the string `jvmRoute`.

XML parsing should be done with an XML parser.

XMLStarlet is a good command-line parser:

```
$ xml ed -u '//Engine/@jvmRoute' -v 'VALUE10' server.xml >server-new.xml
```

This will change the value of the `jvmRoute` attribute of all `Engine` nodes to the string `VALUE10`, and save the resulting XML into `server-new.xml`.

To only change the value for the `Engine` node that has `defaultHost="localhost"`:

```
xml ed -u '//Engine[@defaultHost="localhost"]/@jvmRoute' -v 'VALUE10' server.xml >server-new.xml
```

XMLStarlet is available from http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/, but check your package manager first.  Sometimes the XMLStarlet executable is called `xmlstarlet` rather than `xml`.

Comment: the pb is i can just use `sed` command

Comment: @Mercer Why? Note that virtually _any_ application may be installed in a user's home directory, so even if you don't have root/sudo access on the machine, you will be able to install XMLStarlet.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/patternFrom/patternTo/' file.txt
```

• "s/" means substitute what follows: this substitution must now be applied to our file, by
typing a single line command:

• Commands can be applied by sed only to a selected set of lines. These lines are identified
by their progressive number inside the file, starting from line 1.

For example:

```
sed '2s/patternFrom/patternTo' file.txt
```

• performs the substitution only on the second line

or

```
sed '2,$s/patternFrom/patternTo' file.txt
```

• performs the substitution from line 2 till the last one, identified by the special symbol "$".

Even more

• sed contains an internal buffer, called the hold space. This buffer can be activated
by certain commands, for example 'g'. The 'g' command causes the hold space to replace
the current input line, so that matches can be repeated on the input line

In your case try to match the all occurrences on all lines with:

```
sed 's/patternFrom/patternTo/g' file.txt
```

I think what is not working is the pattern

Make sure the regular expression works, try with

```
sed 's/jvmRoute="[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]*["]/jvmRoute="VALUE10"/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any lines starting with "jvmRoute". (`^` means beginning of line, just omitting that should change the two occurences in your file.)

Comment: this line `<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvmB04905-2">`

Comment: @Mercer No, that line does not start with `jvmRoute`.